# updating a document on cloud function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to update the documents 'state' property to true before the records its updated but its not working.

very simple code::

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
import { CORPORATE_RESOLUTION_VOTE, } from './constants/collections/collections';

admin.initializeApp();


// when a corporate resolution vote is updated,
// use the corporate_resolution_id to get corporate resolution  
// use the corporate_resolution_id to get all the votes  

export const xxxx = functions.firestore
    .document(`${CORPORATE_RESOLUTION_VOTE}/{voteId}`)
    .onUpdate(async (change, context) => {
        console.log('onCorporateResolutionVoteUpdate()');
        const updatedData = change.before.data();

        // Update the 'state' property to true
        const newData = {
            ...updatedData,
            state: true
        };

        // Return the updated data to perform the update
        return change.after.ref.set(newData);

    });
```

this is not working,

I can see the console.log when i update the function.

i tried chatgpt and looking at other answers but nothing is working, help!

Comment: Firestore triggers can't do anything before a change happens.  They can only react to changes that already happened.  `change.before` is just the contents of the document before the update, and `change.after` is the contents after the change happened.  You can compare them to see what already changed in the document to know what exactly happened in the update.

Comment: How do i make a change on After, and not cause an infite loop? @DougStevenson

Comment: That's been discussed on Stack Overflow.  Try a web search.

Comment: @JuanCasas see the [example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events?gen=1st#writing_data_2) in the doc